# How do I configure my Terminal app with bash and iTerm2 with zshell and oh my zsh?

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm, zsh

The Terminal app uses bash by default. And I don't want to change it. However I want to configure iTerm2 with zshell and oh my zsh. and I don't want bash on it. The instructions I checked online, make zshell default in both apps.

Answer (score 54):

If your default system shell is `bash`, your Terminal should start with it. You can check it on General tab under Terminal Preferences. Should look like the following:

[image]

If bash isn't your default shell, you can change it by typing:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

To configure iTerm2 with `zsh` you have to open Preferences and change the command on General tab on your default profile. You have to enter `/bin/zsh` or whatever shell you want.

[image: some text here]

To install oh-my-zsh type the following:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Comment: Should it actually be `chsh -s /bin/bash` (-s, not -c)? I get `chsh: illegal option -- c`...

Comment: Perhaps `/bin/zsh -l`  in the iTerm2 configuration would be closer to what the OP had in mind? BTW, what's the point in doing a `chsh`? The OP said that he already does have bash as default login shell on his platform anyway.

Comment: For me, only `chsh -s /bin/bash` worked. The GUI command did not.

Comment: This is out of date.

Answer (score 4):

**Update Dec 2022**

You need to go to:

1. `Preferences`
2. `Profiles` tab
3. Select `Command` in the drop down
4. Enter `/bin/zsh/` in the text input

[image]